Is attention a kind of K nearest neighbors regressor?
I came up with a strange KNN algorithm that I think is equivalent to self-attention:

Suppose we have a typical (features, label)-style dataset $\mathscr D = \{(x_1, Vx_1), (x_2, Vx_2),\dots, (x_N, Vx_N)\}$, where $x_n$ are vectors and V is some matrix.
In principle, we can apply regular KNN to this set, treating each vector $x_n$ as a query vector and letting $K=|\mathscr D \setminus (x_n, Vx_n)|=N-1$, so everything is a neighbor, no top-K closest vectors:

Given some feature vector $x_n$, compute its similarities to all other vectors: $S(x_n)=\left\{\frac{1}{\lVert x_n - x \rVert} : x \in \mathscr D \setminus x_n\right\}$. I guess this will also require normalization, so that $\sum_i S_i(x_n)=1$.
The output is a weighted sum of labels: $y_n^* = \sum_{i} S_i(x_n) Vx_i$.
Repeat this for all other vectors and get a set of predicted labels corresponding to each feature vector: $\mathscr Y = \{y_1^*, y_2^*, \dots, y_N^*\}$.


Now modify the KNN above like this:

Use dot product as the similarity measure: $s_{Q,K}(x_n, x_m) = x_n' Q'K x_m$.
Now weights for $x_n$ are: $S(x_n)=\mathrm{softmax}\left(\left\{s_{Q,K}(x_n, x) : x \in \mathscr D\right\}\right)$.

We iterate over the entire dataset, including $x_n$ itself, because we can't possibly divide by zero here. IMO, we could as well use $\mathscr D \setminus x_n$ as above.
We use softmax instead of normalizing by $\sum_{x \in \mathscr D \setminus x_n} \frac{1}{\lVert x_n - x \rVert}$.


The predicted label is again $y_n^* = \sum_{i=1}^N S_i(x_n) Vx_i$.


If $Vx_n$ (and thus $y_n^*$) have the same dimensionality, we can stack these algorithms, using $\{y_n^*\}$ as the $\{x_n\}$ for the next layer.

I think my algorithm (2) is 1) the same as self-attention and 2) a kind of KNN, or "all-nearest-neighbors". Thus, it seems like one can understand self-attention as a kind of KNN.
Does this make any sense? Can I think of attention this way?

EDIT: I found some papers that introduce some kind of "continuous nearest neighbors":

"Neural Nearest Neighbors Networks", 2018 (eqns 10-11): https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2018/file/f0e52b27a7a5d6a1a87373dffa53dbe5-Paper.pdf
"KVT: k-NN Attention for Boosting Vision Transformers", 2022 (sec. 3.2 seems to talk about something similar to algorithm (2) above): https://www.ecva.net/papers/eccv_2022/papers_ECCV/papers/136840281.pdf


It's not K-NN since, as you yourself noted, your definition is not that of the K-NN.

@Firebug, I think it's still KNN where I chose $K = |\mathscr D|$, the length of the entire dataset. Sure, this is strange. One might say this defeats the purpose of having "nearest neighbors", but it doesn't because $x_i$ that are very far from the query $x_n$ will receive very small weights and thus won't contribute much to the result. With $K<< |\mathscr D|$, these weights will be exactly zero, so this generalizes KNN.

If you never get the nearest neighbors, what you are doing is not K-NN. It's more akin to kernel smoothing
